# How do I train a deep learning model across multiple virtual machines using PyTorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, distributed-computing

I'm trying to train a model by purchasing multiple virtual machines on a cloud service provider(3-4 instances probably on AWS). I would like to load the model onto each VM, run the training process, then update the models on each VM. The problem is once each model has made its forward pass, I don't know how to accumulate the gradients of each model, and if I could, I'm not sure if I should sum the gradients or average them. I've been using DataParallel on single multiple GPU VMs, so I haven't had to keep track of multiple gradients before this point. I'm unsure if there is a PyTorch package that could help with GPU data parallelism across multiple VMs. I've seen PyTorch Lightning, but it isn't clear what modules to use to communicate between VMs. I'm very new to machine learning, and this is my first training process beyond a single machine. Any advice and tips would be appreciated on this matter including packages or architectural ideas.

Comment: You're looking for [`DistributedDataParallel`](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/ddp_tutorial.html) (DDP).

Comment: @Berriel Thank you for the response. DDP looks like its best package for this, but I'm unsure of how all the VMs communicate with each other using DDP. Do I have to have a list of IPs of each server, or is there some other method by which DDP recognizes each VM and allows communication between all VMs during gradient calculations?